# What exactly does it mean to avoid multiple calls?

Tags: java, list

so I'm in an algorithm class and I've been asked to rewrite a method to avoid multiple calls to indexOf(E e) when using the remove(E e) method inside of the class myAbstractList.java.

> 1.Rewrite the method remove(E e) of class MyAbstractList so as to avoid      multiple calls to indexOf(E e).

I really am not asking anyone to write/complete my project for me. Honestly, I could re-write both classes from memory if I wanted to.

It seems to me that indexOf(E e) doesn't get called *multiple* times anyway so I can't really see how I would go about changing it. I guess it would be helpful if someone could just show me HOW the method would be called multiple times?

## Code

#### MyAbstractList:

---

```
public abstract class MyAbstractList<E> implements MyList<E> {
protected int size = 0; // The size of the list

/**Create a default list*/
protected MyAbstractList() {
}

/**Create a list from an array of objects*/
protected MyAbstractList(E[] objects) {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        add(objects[i]);
    }
}

@Override
/**Return true if this list contains no elements*/
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

@Override
/**Return the number of elements in this list*/
public int size() {
    return size;
}

@Override
// **************************************************************
// **************************************************************
/**Remove the first occurrence of the element e from this list. Shift any
 * subsequent elements to the left. Return true if the element is removed.
 * Must be overridden to avoid multiple calls to indexOf.
 */
// **************************************************************
// **************************************************************
 public boolean remove(E e) {
    if (indexOf(e) >= 0) {
        remove(indexOf(e));
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
}
```

#### MyList:

---

```
public interface MyList<E> extends java.lang.Iterable<E> {

/** Add a new element at the end of this list*/
public void add(E e);

/**Add a new element at the specified index in this list*/
public void add(int index, E e);

/**Clear the list*/
public void clear();

/**Return true if this list contains the element*/
public boolean contains(E e);

/**Return the element from this list at the specified index*/
public E get(int index);

/**Return the index of the first matching element in this list. Return -1 if
 * no match.*/
public int indexOf(E e);

/**Return true if this list contains no elements*/
public boolean isEmpty();

/**Return the index of the last matching element in this list Return -1 if
 * no match.*/
public int lastIndexOf(E e);

/**Remove the first occurrence of the element o from this list. Shift any
 * subsequent elements to the left. Return true if the element is removed.*/
public boolean remove(E e);

/**Remove the element at the specified position in this list Shift any
 * subsequent elements to the left. Return the element that was removed from
 * the list.*/
public E remove(int index);

/**Replace the element at the specified position in this list with the
 * specified element and returns the new set.*/
public Object set(int index, E e);

/** Return the number of elements in this list */
public int size();
}
```

Comment: in the implementation of `remove(E e)` there are two calls to `indexOf` and you should reduce it to one call.

Comment: Okay thank you, this was one of those things that was "so easy I didn't think of it". Like I'm still worried that this is just too easy of answer because of course this was the first thing I thought of when I looked over the question. Since everyone agrees though I'm going to go with it and just ask my professor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public boolean remove(E e) {
if (indexOf(e) >= 0) {
    remove(indexOf(e));
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}}
```

So you have 2 calls to indexOf() in the remove method. Extract the value to a local variable to avoid multiple calls.

Like this:

```
public boolean remove(E e) {
final int index = indexOf(e);
if (index >= 0) {
    remove(index);
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}}
```

Comment: Okay thank you, this was one of those things that was "so easy I didn't think of it". Like I'm still worried that this is just too easy of answer because of course this was the first thing I thought of when I looked over the question. Since everyone agrees though I'm going to go with it and just ask my professor.

Answer (score 1):

The method `remove` currently calls `indexOf` twice. Save the result in a *local variable* and call it once. Something like,

```
public boolean remove(E e) {
    int index = indexOf(e);
    if (index >= 0) {
        remove(index);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Okay thank you, this was one of those things that was "so easy I didn't think of it". Like I'm still worried that this is just too easy of answer because of course this was the first thing I thought of when I looked over the question. Since everyone agrees though I'm going to go with it and just ask my professor.